# No audio when playing HTML5 video on iOS

Tags: html, ios, audio, video

I'm struggling with an issue, which only occurs on iOS platforms, when playing HTML5 videos from websites. The video is playing fine, but there is no audio. I've been looking for a reason and solution since days, found several articles, which mentions issues with HTML5 audio on iOS (with autoplay, muted etc.). Unfortunately nothing helped me to find the cause and solution.

My goal is to have a small video library of HTML5 videos, played directly from the webserver. I wanted to use [lightGallery](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/), but tried native solutions, with and without video tag (just a link to the video file), as well. In each case the video was played without any issues, but there is no audio.

Audio is not muted and the mute switch on the iOS device is not physically switched. When playing the video in a browser on Windows, everything is working as expected.

Any ideas what is causing this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the file?

Comment: Which file? The video?

Comment: The file that won’t play.

Comment: It's the same for all video files. Unfortunately I cannot share the video files.

But that leads me to an idea. I've converted them with VLC. May that is related to the codec used by VLC. I'm gonna check another video, which is not converted with VLC.

I'll give that a shot tomorrow and report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue could be solved by using another audio codec. It seems, that iOS is not willing to play videos created with MP3 audio codec. I've converted the video files again, using MPEG4 (AAC) codec and now everything is working.

Comment: `iOS is not willing to play videos created with MP3 audio codec` didn't know that about iPhone. Am on Windows and have made some MP4 with MP3 audio.